# Google Analytics tracking code doesn't track page views

Tags: google-analytics

I get real time page views with my current tracking code, but pageviews is currenctly 0, even if I visit the page myself and navigate through the website. Can't figure out what's causing this error...

My script

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'neurogavan.se'); // Neuro
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'neurogavan.se', {'name': 'Roxbury'}); // Roxbury

ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

ga('send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for Neuro tracker.
ga('Roxbury.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for Roxbury tracker.
```

My website: http://neurogavan.se/

Comment: Are you filtering out you IP?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine, and I am able to see the pageview hits for both trackers. If you just installed this code on your pages, then it takes at least 24 hours for the data to be processed into your standard reports. As long as you are seeing it in the Real-Time reports, then you should be fine, and only need to wait a bit longer.

Comment: late response, but it now works with above code so your answer was correct, just needed to wait a few hours :)